# Displaying links to records from DB in my Calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, view, iteration

I'm adding a calendar feature to my application, and currently having issues with getting records that I know exist to display in my view.

This is my Controller:

```
class CalendarController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def show
    @date = params[:date] ? Date.parse(params[:date]) : Date.today 
    @service_records_by_date = ServiceRecord.all
  end
end
```

And this is my view:

```
<center><h1>Calendar</h1></center>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <div class="well controls">
      <%= link_to calendar_path(date: @date - 1.month), class: "btn btn-default" do %>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></i>
      <% end %>
      <%= "#{@date.strftime("%B")} #{@date.year}" %>
      <%= link_to calendar_path(date: @date + 1.month), class: "btn btn-default" do %>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></i>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <%= calendar @date do |date| %>
      <%= date.day %>

    <% @service_records_by_date.each do |record| %> 
     <% if record.created_at == date %> 
    <li><%= link_to(record.store_name, record) %></li> 
   <% end %>
    <% end %> 
</ul> 
<% end %>

  </div>
</div>
```

The calendar displays fine seemingly, but no records are populating despite there being many present in the database. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hard to say what the underlying problem is from this, have you tried throwing `puts` in your controllers for your different variables? I'm also wondering if your conditional `if record.created_at == date` might be returning false for some reason. Why don't you take out the conditional and just display both `date` and `record.created_at` to see if they coincide with one another? It might be that your `record.created_at` is stored in a unix time and your `date` might be in a different format, meaning the conditional would return false.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll give it a try. Would information on my model make it easier to see what's going on? Thank you.

Comment: I think after writing out my response I got a better idea of what might be the problem, the first thing I would check are the two things being compared in that conditional.

Comment: Hey Matthew, I puts'ed those variables and discovered that @date is returning a string for the date and not a date/time object. Thanks for helping me figure that out! Not sure how to convert back and forth between the two, but you've given me a direction to try!

Comment: Also, even if `date` is a unix timestamp, how would you compare that value to `record.created_at`? If that timestamp is even a second the date's time off it will not return true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After chatting with you in the comments, we found the problem lied in your conditional:

```
<% if record.created_at == date %> 
    <li><%= link_to(record.store_name, record) %></li>
```

`record.created_at` is likely a unix timestamp.

`date` can also be a unix timestamp, but in this instance it is a string representation of the date (where your problem arises)

I think even if it was a unix timestamp and not a string, you'd still have difficulties comparing the two since unless they're the exact same second you will not be able to successfully compare the two. I would convert both to a common format before comparing.

I think ruby's date object might be helpful for this:

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html